# How to validate a django modelform if the form has some other fields

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have made a Django model form but the problem is in my logic I am using something else and now I want to figure out a way to validate it by either defining a Meta class and choosing the fields that I want to display to the user but of course this won't validate the form.
Now I want to know if there is a way to validate the form without touching the models and pass the data required for the logic and after take care of the information needed for the data of the model to be saved.

Here is the models:

```
from django.db import models

from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


# Create your models here.
class RoomCategory(models.Model):
    name      = models.CharField(max_length=59)
    price     = models.IntegerField()
    beds      = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    capacity  = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    size      = models.CharField(max_length=59)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Room(models.Model):
    room_number = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    room_category = models.ForeignKey(RoomCategory, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"The room {self.room_number} {self.room_category} has a maximum of {self.room_category.capacity} person and cost {self.room_category.price}/night "
    

class Booking(models.Model):   
    customer    = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    room        = models.ForeignKey(RoomCategory, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    check_in    = models.DateField()
    check_out   = models.DateField()
    adults      = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
    children    = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.customer} has booked for {self.room} from {self.check_in} to {self.check_out}"
```

Here is the form:

```
class BookingForm(forms.ModelForm):

   class Meta:
       model = Booking
       fields = ['room', 'check_in', 'check_out', 'adults', 'children']
```

here is the views.py

```
 data       = form.cleaned_data
        roomlist         = Room.objects.filter(room_category__name=data['room'])
        available_rooms  = []
        for room in roomlist:
            if data['adults'] + data['children'] > room.room_category.capacity:
                return HttpResponse(f'Sorry !! But this category of room cannot handle more than {room.room_category.capacity}')
            else:
            
                if check_availability(room.room_category.name, data['check_in'], data['check_out'], data['adults'], data['children']):
                
                    available_rooms.append(room)
            

        if len(available_rooms) > 0:
            room = available_rooms[0]
            new_booking = Booking.objects.create(
                customer=self.request.user,
                room=room,
                check_in=data['check_in'],
                check_out=data['check_out'],
                adults=data['adults'],
                children=data['children']
            )
            new_booking.save()
            
            return HttpResponse(new_booking)
        else:
            return HttpResponse('All the rooms of this type are not available')
```

It is not printing the data means that the form is not valid and it fall down to the else statement.

Comment: To be more precious by the way in  the  logic I am using a room category instance and in the form I am using a room instance

Answer (score 0):

You can validate any field in the form by writing a method in this way : `def clean_(field_name)` i.e `def clean_room(self)` read more:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-a-specific-field-attribute

Comment: But  the main problem is that in the booking model I am passing in a category room instance and based on that category I will get all the rooms but once I get the logic the check_availability function need a room category instance not a room instance so the code will throw an error